# calculate button question, html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, radio-button

i just changed my question to show my attempt at it. This is what im trying to do. The XPlevels have a set value, and using that i wanna calculate and display the price

```js
function setprice() {    
    var val;    
    var type = document.getElementByName("XP")
    if (type[0].checked)
    {
        var val = 200;
    }
    else if (type[1].checked)
    {
        var val = 150;
    }
    else if (type[2].checked)
    {
        var val = 100;
    }
}

function Calculate() {
    var FName = document.getElementById("FName");
    var numppl = document.getElementById("numppl");
    var Tprice = val * numppl;
    window.alert(FName + ", the membership amount is: R " + BasePrice);
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="XP" value="Novice" onclick="setprice" />Novice
<input type="radio" name="XP" value="Intermediate"  onclick="setprice" />Intermediate
<input type="radio" name="XP" value="Expert"  onclick="setprice" />Expert

<label for="Members">Number of members</label>
<input id="numppl" type="number" name="Members" size="2" />

<input type="button" value="Calculate fee" onclick="Calculate"/>
```

Comment: What's your problem with this? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onclick** event on the Calculate Fee Button to call a JavaScript Function that checks which radio button is selected.

```js
const calculateFee = () => {
    let radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
    if(radioButtons[i].checked){
        console.log(`Checked Radio Button is : ${radioButtons[i].value}`);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="XP" value="Novice" />Novice
<input type="radio" name="XP" value="Intermediate" checked />Intermediate
<input type="radio" name="XP" value="Expert" />Expert
<br />
<label for="Members">Number of members</label>
<input type="number" name="Members" size="2" />



<input type="button" value="Calculate fee" onclick="calculateFee()"/>
```

Comment: so woudl i be able to set a specif val to every radio button

Comment: because i want to capture which is selected and using a corresponding preset value multiply it by the entered amount of people to come up with a cost

Comment: You can specify the Value of each radio button then get multiply where I have have used console.log

Comment: how do i specify the val ive never seen this method before

Answer (score 0):

**This is an edit of your JS code**

```js
function setprice() {
    var type = document.querySelectorAll('[name="XP"]'); 
    if (type[0].checked) {
        var val = 200;
    }
    else if (type[1].checked) {
        var val = 150;
    }
    else if (type[2].checked) {
        var val = 100;
    }

    return val;
}

function calculate() {
    var fName = document.getElementById("FName");
    var numppl = document.getElementById("numppl");
    var val = setprice();
    var tprice = val * numppl.value;
    // window.alert(FName + ", the membership amount is: R " + BasePrice);
    console.log(tprice);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="XP" value="Novice" onclick="setprice" />Novice
<input type="radio" name="XP" value="Intermediate" onclick="setprice" />Intermediate
<input type="radio" name="XP" value="Expert" onclick="setprice" />Expert

<label for="Members">Number of members</label>
<input id="numppl" type="number" name="Members" size="2" />

<input type="button" value="Calculate fee" onclick="calculate()" />
```

**This example a more correct approach to what you want**

On each radio button, the value is the number (unit price) to be calculated. I have added a `data` attribute from which to take "Type"

The input named `member` must be set to a minimum value so that the user cannot set a negative value.

Try this code and if you have any questions I will supplement my answer!

```js
var radio = document.querySelectorAll('.radio');
var number = document.querySelector('.number');
var button = document.querySelector('.button');
var getval;
var datainf;

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    radio.forEach(function (el) {
        if (el.checked) {
            getval = +el.value;
            datainf = el.getAttribute('data');
        }
    });

    var result = getval * number.value;
    console.log( 'Quantity: ' + number.value + ' / Type: ' + datainf + ' / The membership amount is: ' + result);
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="XP" value="200" data="Novice" />Novice
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="XP" value="150" data="Intermediate" checked />Intermediate
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="XP" value="100" data="Expert" />Expert
<br />

<label for="Members">Number of members</label>
<input type="number" class="number" name="Members" size="2" value="1" min="1" />

<input type="button" class="button" value="Calculate fee" />
```

Comment: i just altered my question so u cud see a clearer attempt at what im trying to do. it wont work for some reason

Comment: its not linked to calculate fee

Comment: id like to display it using the name in a p below

Comment: @margiela I supplemented my answer! Please look again.